# Millions of folders lead to unresponsive USB

Tags: 18.04, usb, directory, c++

I ended up doing an experiment to see how many folders I could fit on a 16GB USB (for fun) So I got a raspberry pi, and ran the program to generate new folders until it crashed.

When I plug the drive in my main computer, and navigate to it in terminal, /media/username/
and I type ls, the program gets hung up trying to find it. Secondly, opening it up in the default disk manager freezes the program when you click on the drive. Lastly, Nautilis works, but it's in a long loop that goes nowhere after an hour. (The USB is an NTFS file system with over 3 million folders)

Do I just use gparted and wipe the device? Or is there a way to access these folders?

Thanks,
Moose

Comment: How many folders have you managed to create?

Comment: As described in the post, the USB is formatted with the NTFS file system, and has over 3 million folders.

Comment: Oops, sorry I missed that. This is an awesome experiment! I hope someone will answer your question. I too would like to know what eventually causes the drive to hang and whether it can be solved.

Comment: I'm a little dissapointed people downvoted this question so much, but what can you do? I basically am trying to directly compare FAT file systems and NTFS and EXT4... the cool thing is, is that purely in file names, it takes up 3GB of memory!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe ls through less or more if you want to see some of the folder names (or even grep to refine which folders).

You ought to be able to use rmdir to remove some or all of those directories as well.

If you need code examples, let me know; but the commands are pretty clear to use.

Comment: Yeah I should be able to read the man and figure it out. I'll look into it later, but it there a specific way to read the last folder created?

Comment: I suppose you could sort by timestamp?  Again I'd have to refer to the man pages for sorting by timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

> The file system uses an index table stored on the device to identify chains of data storage areas associated with a file, the File Allocation Table (FAT). ***The FAT is statically allocated at the time of formatting***. The table is a linked list of entries for each cluster, a contiguous area of disk storage. Each entry contains either the number of the next cluster in the file, or else a marker indicating the end of the file, unused disk space, or special reserved areas of the disk. The root directory of the disk contains the number of the first cluster of each file in that directory. The operating system can then traverse the FAT, looking up the cluster number of each successive part of the disk file as a cluster chain until the end of the file is reached. Sub-directories are implemented as special files containing the directory entries of their respective files.

(Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#Concepts). Emphasis mine.)

You can ***statically allocate*** the FAT of a [VFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#VFAT) file system when you format the drive using the command `mkfs.vfat`. VFAT is the most widely supported file system for USB flash drives and is supported by all operating systems. NTFS originates from Windows and is a lot more advanced, but the following concepts are still helpful to understand.

From `man mkfs.vfat`:

> ```
>    -f NUMBER-OF-FATS
>        Specify the number of file allocation tables in the filesystem.  The
>        default is 2.
>
>    -F FAT-SIZE
>        Specifies the type of file allocation tables used (12, 16 or 32 bit).
>        If nothing is specified,  mkfs.fat will automatically select between 
>        12, 16 and 32 bit, whatever fits better for the filesystem size.
>
>    -r ROOT-DIR-ENTRIES
>        Select the number of entries available in the root directory.  The
>        default is 112 or 224 for floppies and 512 for hard disks.
> ```

Since the FAT of a VFAT filesystem have a statically allocated size, which can't change later, there is only a limited number of files that it can store. Here is the continuation of the Wikipedia article referenced above:

> Each entry in the FAT linked list is a fixed number of bits: 12, 16 or 32. The maximum size of a file or a disk drive that can be accessed is the product of the largest number that can be stored in the entries (less a few values reserved to indicate unallocated space or the end of a list) and the size of the disk cluster. Even if only one byte of storage is needed to extend a file, an entire cluster must be allocated to it, so large clusters waste much disk space if there are large numbers of small files.

This means that the number of files you can store on a file system is completely dependent on the size that was allocated when the drive was formatted. However, there are [theoretical maximums](https://superuser.com/questions/446282/max-files-per-directory-on-ntfs-vol-vs-fat32) that cannot be exceeded:

- The maximum number of files for a VFAT filesystem is 268,435,437
- The maximum number of files for an NTFS filesystem is 4,294,967,295

Finally, none of this is of much relevance when you're an Ubuntu user. Traditionally, Unix-like filesystems don't use neither the VFAT nor the NTFS filesystem. A Unix-like filesystem has no FAT or MFT but allocates an *inode table* which stores [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). A major difference between Windows-like (VFAT, NTFS) filesystems and Unix-like (ext2, ext3, ext4) is that Unix does not store the filename in the allocation table, but inside special files called *directories*. Traditionally, an often celebrated difference is that [fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_fragmentation) is less of an issue on Unix than on Windows.

So, to get maximum usability out of your broken drive, reformat it with the command `mkfs.ext4` or `mke2fs`. Be sure to read the man page first!

Comment: Well considering I have only 3 million files, I don't think it's going to be very relevant for the NTFS file system. Though I definately will retry this experiment with FAT sooner or later.